# PHP - Create multidimensional array via a loop based on a count

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, multidimensional-array

Having some trouble coming up with the right combination of count and foreach for a multidimensional array.

I'm currently doing the following to create an associative array from my db's returned result:

```
$sql = "SELECT g.id, g.shortname FROM games g ORDER BY g.id ASC";
        $query = $this->db->query($sql);

        if($query->num_rows() > 0):
            foreach($query->result() as $row):
                $data[$row->id] = $row->shortname;
            endforeach;
        return $data;
        else:
            return false;
        endif;
```

This of course produces the following array (which works fine; semi-faux code):

```
array ( [1] => CoolGame, [2] => AnotherGame, [3] => BetterGame, [4] => UglyGame)
```

....and so on

But what I want to do is automatically break up results (based on a count var/limiter) into groups via a multidimensional array like so:

```
array (Group 1 => 
         array([1] => CoolGame [2] => AnotherGame),
       Group 2 =>  
         array([3] => BetterGame [4] => UglyGame)
)
```

So in that example, my `$depth_count = 2;`

In case anyone is interested, I'm doing this to work with auto-generated `<optgroup>` tags for a multi select via CI's form helper's form_multiselect() function.
Need some help with tweaking my PHP to allow for this. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use php's [array_chunk](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php) method. Notice its use in modified code below:

```
if($query->num_rows() > 0):
    foreach($query->result() as $row):
        $data[$row->id] = $row->shortname;
    endforeach;

    $data = array_chunk($data, 2);

return $data;
```

Comment: +1, Touche. I forgot about that function. I actually like that, if it's arbitrary grouping.

Comment: +1 array_chunk (very useful function while playing with arrays :))

Comment: Cool stuff. Works perfectly and would be the complete solution except for the fact that it creates numerically indexed array keys. I can probably iterate over the array after the fact and prepend "Group" to each key name.

Answer (score 1):

```
$nGroup = 1; $curGroup = '';
$nRow = 0;
foreach ($query->result() as $row){
  if ($nRow++ % 2 == 0){ // change 2 to your limiter
    $curGroup = 'Group ' . $nGroup++;
    $data[$curGroup] = array();
  }
  $data[$curGroup][$row->id] = $row->shortname;
}
```

Something like that? Keep track of the row you're on, the current group your adding to, and the group name. Then, every 2nd (or Nth) set, switch groups.